# any way to simplify this if/else block?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
 function (flag) {
 if (flag) {
 let id = "name",key = "age"
 return {id,key};
 } else {
 let id = "boy",key = "girl"
 return {id,key};
 }
 }
```

Any other readable solutions to handle this if/else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple options aside from what's already been answered:

```
const flagCheck = flag => {
    const id = flag ? 'name' : 'boy';
    const key = flag ? 'age' : 'girl';
    return { id, key };
};
```

```
const flagCheck = flag => ({
    id: flag ? 'name': 'boy',
    key: flag ? 'age': 'girl'
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider just returning the plain object, rather than defining independent variables beforehand. You can also consider using the conditional operator and implicit return of an arrow function to cut down on the syntax noise, if you want:

```
const flagFn = flag => flag
  ? { id: 'name', key: 'age' }
  : { id: 'boy', key: 'girl' };
```